# Unbrick Tenda W1801R router

Tags: wireless-router, firmware, tftp

I have been running Tomato v132 on my Tenda W1801R router and few days ago, I decided to update to the latest firmware.

After flashed with v140, it worked fine for a few days. Then all of a sudden, the router doesn't assign IP and not broadcasting the SSID anymore. Tried 30/30/30 hard reset with no success.

I tried to connect to it via a network cable and setup the desktop to use static IP, couldn't get an IP either.

Tried to upload the old firmware with TFTP, but the client couldn't get a connection. So, is it really done?

Comment: Open the case, and look for a three- or four-pin header that might be a serial console.  (The circuit board might only have solder pads, and not have the header installed.)  Get a FTDI or similar USB-to-3.3v_TTL_serial adapter to connect to this header.

Comment: @sawdust you are right, there is no header to plug in a FTDI cable. So this router is done.